# Dúvida com relação ao operador ||= do ruby

Tags: ruby

Olá ainda estou iniciando em ruby, e possuo uma dúvida em relação ao seguinte código

Main.rb

```
web_design = Livro.new "Ruby", "X", "9428", 56.40, :web_design
android_dev = Livro.new "Java", "Y", "9385", 78.9, :android_dev
game_dev = Livro.new "Unity", "Z", "9420", 67.5, :game_dev

biblioteca = Biblioteca.new

biblioteca.adiciona web_design
biblioteca.adiciona android_dev
biblioteca.adiciona game_dev

for categoria,livros in biblioteca.livros do
    p categoria
    for livro in livros do
        p livro.preco
    end
end
```

Biblioteca.rb

```
class Biblioteca

    attr_reader :livros

    def initialize
        @livros = []
    end

    def adiciona(livro)
        @livros[livro.categoria] ||= [] 
        @livros[livro.categoria] << livro
    end

    def livros
        @livros.values.flatten
    end
end
```

Basicamente quanto tento adicionar livros a biblioteca, o compilador me devolve o seguinte erro "Biblioteca.rb:11: in []: no implicit conversion of symbol into integer ".

Pesquisei um pouco sobre o error, e seria devido ao fato de eu estar tratando um array como um hash.

```
def adiciona(livro)
    @livros[livro.categoria] ||= [] 
    @livros[livro.categoria] << livro
end
```

Além de esse trecho acima indicar o erro, pra ser bem franco a sua finalidade ainda não ficou muito clara.

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Você está inicializando @livros como um array `@livros = []`. Você deveria inicializar como um hash `@livros = {}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Primeiro, vamos entender o que **||=** significa no seu código. Basicamente, e para facilitar o entendimento, você pode traduzir o código para algo mais didático como:

```
def adiciona(livro)
    @livros[livro.categoria] = @livros[livro.categoria] || []
    @livros[livro.categoria] << livro
end
```

Para ficar AINDA mais claro, esse código poderia ser traduzido para algo assim também:

```
def adiciona(livro)
    @livros[livro.categoria] = [] unless @livros[livro.categoria]
    @livros[livro.categoria] << livro
end
```

Ou seja, caso **@livros[livro.categoria]** seja **nil** (portanto, será avaliado como **false**), então um array vazio será atribuído à variável. Caso contrário, a variável manterá o valor que ela já tem. Mas seu código ficará mais limpo e claro se você usar apenas **||=**, concorda? :)

Agora falando sobre o seu problema. A questão é que você está atribuindo um Array vazio para a variável **@livros** e depois está tentando tratar ela como um Hash. Simplesmente mude o código do seu construtor para:

```
def initialize
    @livros = {}
end
```

Comment: Cara muito obrigado, ficou bem mais claro o uso do ||=, resolveu o problema também, foi desatenção da minha parte.

Comment: Opa! Excelente, @wagnermps!